# "Work two jobs" vs. "work at two jobs"

Tags: prepositions, collocations

Could you tell me which one of the following sentence is more correct and natural?

> I had to **work two jobs** to get by when I lived in the expensive city.
>
> I had to **work at two jobs** to get by when I lived in the expensive city

Are both perfectly good?

Comment: I wouldn't say _work a job_. You could say _work at_, or "I had to (have), (do), (take) or even (hold down) two jobs..."

Comment: AmE: The first one. The second sounds like you're trying but not succeeding -- ex: I worked at the counter for a while, but it just wouldn't come clean.

Comment: If a context is well defined, both will be natural. The context is employment. If a context is not well defined, the former will be a lexically contradictive sentence. There are other senses of the word *job* that can collocate with the verb *work* . For example, *Can you play drums? Sullivan: I play drums, and I have worked jobs on thern*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are perfectly acceptable, example 1 sounds slightly more natural.  Note that the rule is not universal.

"Work two jobs" is acceptable.
"Work one job full time" is acceptable.
"Work at MacDonalds and at the office" is acceptable.

"Work MacDonalds and the office" is **not** acceptable.